# I'm not a programmer: does 'throw' mean a specific code element or is a general term like 'show'?

Tags: throw

For example:

> An unguarded **throw** of type {0} was detected. Refactor this code to either throw an exception of type InvalidPluginExecutionException or guard against thrown exceptions of other types.

What could the first 'throw' mean? Is it a synonym for 'show' or 'return'?

Comment: What language is this? What framework / libraries are you using? In general Including more info will help others answer.

Comment: I'm translating Microsoft PowerApps Analysis service and I'm not programming myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most languages allow the "throwing" of exceptions. If a function throws an exception, it means that under certain logic paths it chooses not to gracefully handle an problem and passes it on to the user to handle.

In your case, it would seem:

- you are using a typed language
- the compiler knows which functions throw exceptions
- the compiler does not allow / warns against unhandled (unguarded) exceptions

You are likely using a function that can throw an exception under certain cases and your code does not "catch" (handle) that exception, leading to certain cases in which your code is implicitly throwing an exception despite you not explicitly writing any exception throwing code. The compiler is telling you to handle the implicit case by handling the exception (in most languages this is accomplished with some sort of "try..catch") and:

- explicitly throw the exception
- gracefully handle the exception